# Complex SELECT SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

There are some classes. Students in the classes learn subjects. I connected these tables to each over so: For 1 class there will be many subjects, for 1 subjects there will be many classes. `Subject M <=> M Class`. So I have 3 tables in my database to create these relationships:

Subject:

```
+----+------+
+ id + name +
+----+------+
```

Class:

```
+----+-------+------+
+ id + digit + char +
+----+-------+------+
```

ClassVsTeacher (to connect these 2 tables):

```
+----+----------+------------+
+ id + class_id + subject_id +
+----+----------+------------+
```

TeacherVsClass (important for 2nd question, to connect classes and teachers):

```
+----+----------+------------+
+ id + class_id + teacher_id +
+----+----------+------------+
```

1) Am I right?

2)  I am working on adding subject to a class now. **I want to show in drop-down all subjects which has at least 1 teacher, except subjects current class already connected with.**

I know how to show all subjects which has at least 1 teacher:

```
select 
    `s`.`id`, `s`.`name`
from `Subject` as `s`
where 
    `s`.`id` in (select `subject_id` from `TeacherVsSubject`)
```

It works fine, but I can't understand how to show this, except subjects which is already conneted to current class. This is my question.

Comment: Is one subject taught by only one teacher? Or many teachers can teach one subject?

Comment: Note for readability, you don't need to backtick-escape every name in MySQL, only those that are also keywords.

Comment: I think you meant `ClassVsSubject`?

Comment: @Prodikl, sure `ClassVsSubject`. @Dai, okay, thank you. @hashbrown, many teachers can teach one subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
select * from Subject
where id in (select subject_id from TeacherVsSubject)
and id not in (select subject_id from ClassVsSubject where class_id = XX)
```

We select all Subjects, if there are row with same `id` in `TeacherVsSubject` and there are no any rows with same `id` in ClassVsSubject with that class = `XX`. `XX` = `id` of class, for which I am going to add subject.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track.

I'd use table names like:

`SubjectsPerClass`

and

`TeachersPerClass`

Then I'd create a join statement and save that as a view, then query the view from now on

```
SELECT * 
FROM `SubjectsPerClass` sc
JOIN `Subject` s
   ON `s`.`id` = `sc`.`subject_id`
JOIN `Class` c
   ON `c`.`id` = `sc`.`class_id`
```

Then if you're using phpMyAdmin just click `Create View` at the end. I usually name the view something like `ClassesInfo` (I use `Info` for the views). You could optionaly select which fields you want.

Then in the future you could do

```
SELECT *
FROM `ClassesInfo`
WHERE (conditions here)
```

Comment: Okay. Now I has result, which shows all subjects for all classes. Is it answer for my question? The question was: I want to show in drop-down all subjects which has at least 1 teacher, except subjects current class already connected with. How to do it. I know how to get subjects which has teachers, but I don't know how to filter out subjects which are already connected with class. That's the question. Anyway, thank you for you answer!

Comment: After you make a `view`, then you could do `SELECT * FROM ClassesInfo WHERE teacher_id != null AND class_id != 12`. Of course put your current class id in there

Comment: Arg. I have so bad english ?:( I am working on managing subjects of classes. For example, now user is on 'class profile' page. He press 'add subject' and drop-down list with subjects is appearing. Question about how to get this list. Subjects, which will be suggested to user would be (what subjects would be in this list): show all subjects, which are not linked with this class (User already added this subject to this class) and all subjects must have at least 1 teacher. Do you understand me now? You try to help me to manage existing subjects, which are already linked to class. I don't need it.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's quite confusing. In the end, the example here should show you how to do this with any other combination of data. You could make another `View` with a longer set of joins, joining in `TeachersPerClass`, etc. And then `select`ing what you need. Have you used `MySQL Workbench` and tried making an `EER` diagram? That might help you visualize your data better.

Comment: Don't get what is the problem. Check answer for solution.